# Paypal Payment with hidden form in php not secured.

Tags: php, paypal

I have this paypal form for a small shopping site. The problem is that the paypal form passes the form data in an hidden form which is not secured at all. As I can use the firebug and edit the price in the hidden form to pay less amount before checking out.

This is what i have tried

1.) I have tried to use session but I still have to print it within the hidden form value as in case below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_session['amount']); ?>">
```

2.)There is no way i can pass amount in session variable to Paypal submission page(https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr)

my question is, which way do I ensure that the hidden form data will not be tampered by a thief who can change the price of the product via firebug and then check out with paypal.

here is the script

```
<?php
session_start();
$_session['amount'] =30;

$paypal_url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; // Test Paypal API URL
$paypal_id='myemail@gmail.com'; // Business email ID
?>
<h4>Welcome, Guest</h4>

<div class="product">            

    <div class="name">
        Television
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        Price:$30
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
    <form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Television">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30">

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://mysite/payment_with_paypal/cancel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite/payment_with_paypal/success.php">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't POST directly to PayPal, instead POST to your server to verify the amounts you have in session then send it off to PayPal

Comment: @kisaragi. I have already done but who will still click the submission button for paypal